# Can untrusted data be used in a URL when using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, jsx

My understanding is that [React will automatically escape values in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks).  However I've read that [it's not always safe](https://snyk.io/blog/10-react-security-best-practices/) to rely on React to escape everything for you.  I want to load an image which will contain a URL that includes some untrusted data.

```
<img src={`/public/userImages/${imageID}`} />
```

Is the code above considered safe?  The variable imageID contains user input and is untrusted.

Comment: Short answer: the URL looks OK as-is.

Comment: Though you are using React, the React framework doesn't have much to do with processing CSS this way. If you are concerned about uncontrolled/user specified image urls then you should sanitize this manually yourself.

Comment: @DrewReese I would disagree.   I am directly referring to React DOM's ability to sanitize user input.  https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks

Comment: Ok, then ask a question about JSX and the DOM, not CSS and styling.

Comment: @DrewReese The method in which I load the URL is irrelevant to my question.  Regardless, I've edited my question to reflect loading the image through an img tag instead of as a backgroundImage.  Does this satisfy your request?

Answer (score -1):

While it is true that [React DOM will sanitize data](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks) entered into JSX, it seems the following is considered bad practice:

```
<img src={data} />
```

While the following is [considered safer](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/spasecurity/react-xss-part1.html)

```
<img src={`/public/userImages/${data}`} />
```

Ideally it sounds like you should still sanitize the data with a library such as [dompurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) or [Angular's URL sanitizer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/sanitization/url_sanitizer.ts).  If there is a better or safer approach I would love to hear it, I'm not quite sure why this question has received so many down votes (show's research effort, clear/concise?)